# Footer not showing image

Tags: html, css

While I was trying to style my footer, and checking it in Firefox, i encountered an error that the facebook, etc icons were not showing up. This is the sample footer html code.

```
<div id="footer">
        <div id="footer_content">   
            <div id="footer_left">      
                <!-- JP Morgan && Force For Good Signature -->
                <div id="jp_right_content_main">
                    <div id="jp_right_content_inner1">
                        <font color="#FFFFFF" size="4" font-family="Times New Roman">In Assocaition with:</font> <br /> <img
                            class="header-photo" width="280" height="70" alt="JPM Logo"
                            src="images/Logo_JPM.jpg"></img>
                        <h1 class="header11">
                            <font color="#ED872D">Force</font> <font color="white">For</font> <font
                                color="green">Good</font>
                        </h1>
                    </div>              
                <div id="right_content_inner2">
                    <img src="images/partner_pic.png" width="130" height="130" />
                </div>                  
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer_right">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/Unitedwaymumbai" target="_new"><img
                    src="United%20Way%20Mumbai%20--%20about_us_files/facebook.gif"
                    height="27" width="16"></a><a
                    href="http://www.youtube.com/unitedwaymumbai" target="_new"><img
                    src="United%20Way%20Mumbai%20--%20about_us_files/youtube.gif"
                    height="27" width="34"></a><a
                    href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/united-way-of-mumbai"
                    target="_new"><img
                    src="United%20Way%20Mumbai%20--%20about_us_files/linkdin.gif"
                    height="27" width="26"></a><a
                    href="http://twitter.com/mumbaihelpline" target="_new"><img
                    src="United%20Way%20Mumbai%20--%20about_us_files/tweeter.gif"
                    height="27" width="32"></a><br>

                    <p class="text7">
                    Copyright United Way Mumbai & J.P.MORGAN SERVICS INDIA PVT LTD. All
                    Rights Reserved. <a href="sitemap.htm"><span class="text8">Sitemap</span>
                    </a>Page Designing By <a href="http://www.force4g.com"
                        target="_blank" class="text8">FORCE FOR GOOD | TEAM : T.U.R.C.S</a>.
                </p>
                <div id="contact_text" class="header5">Contact: 022-24937676 / 79
                        or Email: contact@unitedwaymumbai.org</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And its corresponding css:

```
#footer{width:100%; height:auto; border:0px solid black; float:left; background:url('../images/footer_bg.gif') repeat-x;}
#footer_content {width:959px; height:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-bottom:30px }
#footer_left {width:491px; float:left; margin-top:16px; margin-bottom:25px;  }
#footer_right {width:468px; float:left; margin-top:16px; }
#jp_right_content_main { height:159px; width:468px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0; background-image:url(../images/partner_bg.png); background-repeat:no-repeat}
#jp_right_content_inner1 {width:311px; height:127px; margin-left:27px; float:left;  margin-top:5px;}
```

The facebook, twitter etc png images are not showing up.

Any help would be appericiated.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: Can you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Comment: Sorry but i am not sure how to put images there... since this concerns mostly with images.

Comment: Can you change the image src attributes to full URLs instead of partial URLs?

Comment: Those are some nasty <font> tags

Comment: I think the issue was in the src: src="United%20Way%20Mumbai%20--%20about_us_files/tweeter.gif" When i changed them to relative path, it worked. @MisterMelancholy Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the moral of the story is: Make sure your images are linked correctly.

And for future reference, setting things up on sites like [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) not only helps other people troubleshoot your problem, but gives you a chance to redo what you've already done and catch small errors (like this one).